# edit user form angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so here's my github for my recent project: https://github.com/ryanwaite28/form-site
its a form site where you can create and edit users. I got the create functionality working, however the edit isn't
when you click edit, i want to pass the user info into the edit function's parameters but i can't seem to get it right. i want to set the user's info to that of which is in the input box. is there something i'm doing wrong? Also, im using angular JS and jQuery.

Comment: Can you post your code here? And describe problem are you encountering. Here is a link for How to ask a question of StackOverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: <br><button type="button" ng-click="saveChanges(user)"/>Save Changes</button><button type="button" ng-click="undo()">Exit</button>
       <b><p id="message-two"></p></b>   $scope.editUser = function(user) {
  console.log("Edit Function Working");
  $scope.hideForm = false;
  
  $('#edit-firstname').text('');
  $('#edit-lastname').text('');
  $('#edit-email').text('');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the user to the function in the html:

```
<td><button type="button" id="edit-btn" ng-click="editUser(user)">Edit</button></td>
```

Also, you need to reference the form of the "in edit" user somehow like:

```
$scope.editUser = function(user) {
    $scope.userBeingEdited = user;
}
```

And reference the html of the edit form to this userBeingEdited part of the scope.

The saveChanges method should not be inside the edit function. Should be a separate function in which you can commit changes

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know i have to fill in the parameter in the html. before, it said user not defined when i did it in javascript. But one more thing. if i take the save changes function out of the edit scope, how can i save the changes? the save changes will be in another scope and wont know what to save?

Comment: The scope is controller-defined, not function-defined. The scope will be shared between functions.